# Knockout Error: Found End Comment Without a Matching opening comment, as child of [object Text]

Tags: magento2, error, knockoutjs, fatal-error, knockout

I'm getting a KO error complaining about a missing opening tag regarding the following code. I don't know much about KO but it looks like the the KO tags all match up.

```
<!-- ko if: (visibleAddress)-->
```

```
<div class="step-title opc-block-summary"  data-role="title">
    <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {name: 'selectshipping', id:'branchpickupshipping', value: 'branchpickupshipping',checked: checkBranchPickupSelected()},click:showBranchPickupAddress">Click & Collect
</div>
<div id="branchpickup-iframe-popup-modal">
    <div id="show-branch-cartpopup"></div>
</div>
<div id="branch-pickup-grid">    
<div class="field addresses" id="branchpickup-addresses">
    <div class="control">
        <div class="shipping-address-items branchpickup-shipping-address-items">
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
            <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="branch-grid-loader"></div>      
    
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Can you please specify the file path and steps you were following ?